# Why does jQuery not see a checkbox has been auto checked?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have some jQuery checking to see when a human clicks a check button but if the page loads with the button marked as checked already, the jQuery doesn't work.

```
    $ (function(){
        var requiredCheckboxes = $('.options :checkbox[required]');
        requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
            if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
                requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
            } else {
                requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
            }
        });
    });
```

What I need this to do is if the checkbox is already checked, it removes the required attribute. Why is it not working when a variable is posted to the page and PHP adds checked="checked" to the input?

Thanks!

Comment: I should clarify, this is to check to ensure one of the check boxes is checked during validation.

Comment: I need something like requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked') || and this bit checks to see if it is checked already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this` as selector on checking if the clicked checkbox is checked or not. `this` refers to the clicked checkbox. You can use `prop()` to add and remove `required`

```js
var requiredCheckboxes = $('.options');

requiredCheckboxes.change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('required', false);
  } else {
    $(this).prop('required', true);
  }
});
```

```css
input:required {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='options' type="checkbox" required>
<input class='options' type="checkbox" required>
<input class='options' type="checkbox" required>
<input class='options' type="checkbox" required>
```

---

**Update:** You can use a class for the required checkbox and use `prop()` to add and remove `required` property.

```js
var requiredCheckboxes = $('.required-options')

//On page Loads
if (requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
  requiredCheckboxes.prop('required', false);
} else {
  requiredCheckboxes.prop('required', true);
}


//Event listener
requiredCheckboxes.change(function() {
  if (requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
    requiredCheckboxes.prop('required', false);
  } else {
    requiredCheckboxes.prop('required', true);
  }
});
```

```css
input:required {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='required-options' type="checkbox" required checked>
<input class='required-options' type="checkbox" required>
<input class='required-options' type="checkbox" required>
<input class='required-options' type="checkbox" required>
```

Comment: I see what you mean but this only removes the required from the checked box. I need the required to be removed from all the checked boxes.

Comment: The idea is to require only one checked box.

Comment: This works when no boxes are checked but, alas, when the page loads with a box already checked, jQuery doesn't see the box is checked and doesn't remove the required attributes.

Comment: @EricTheRed On the page load you have to check if the checkbox is checked and do the process. I updated the code

Comment: You might need to put those codes on a function to remove repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

js:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$('body').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', "checked");
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/tj6chfaz/1/)